# modprobe.d wrong driver on reboot, don't want to blacklist generic driver [Ubuntu 18.04, Aquantia/Marvell 5G USB Dongle]

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, ethernet, modprobe

`modprobe.d` not using the designated driver after reboot.

- Aquantia/Marvell/Sabrent 5G USB Ethernet USB dongle (NT-SS5G).
- Ubuntu Server 18.04.6 LTS (4.15.0-166-generic)

Driver `aqc111` installed. 
`/etc/modprobe.d/usbnic.conf` file created:

```
   alias usb:v2ECApC101d0101dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFip00in00 aqc111
   alias usb:v2ECApC101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic02isc06ip00in*1 aqc111
   alias usb:v2ECApC101d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc*ip*in* aqc111
```

(yes, only need the first alias, at the try-anything stage) 
Disabling `cdc_ether`, 
Unplugging, plugging back in ethernet dongle:

```
    $ rmmod cdc_ether
```

`aqc111` driver being used:

```
    $ lsusb -t
    /:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=aqc111, 5000M
```

Upon reboot, `cdc_ether` used:

```
    $ lsusb -t
    /:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 5000M
```

Don't want to blacklist `cdc_ether`, 
Under the impression the `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf` should be prioritized, 
Understand `cdc_ether` also matches the vendor/device ID, 
What am I missing so `aqc111` is the driver assigned after reboot? 
Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to add the module/driver to `/etc/modules`. No need to blacklist `cdc_ether`, correct driver used after reboot.

```
$ nano /etc/modules
```

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
aqc111
```

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=aqc111, 5000M
```